# powering contact form with php

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I am trying to power my contact form with the following HTML and PHP, and when I enter information and press enter, I always get an Error!

**HTML**

```
<form action="contact.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" placeholder="your name" name="name">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Your Email" name="email">
  <textarea placeholder="Your Message" name="message"></textarea>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $formcontent=" From: $name \n Email: $email \n Message: $message";
  $recipient = "jainkenul@gmail.com";
  $subject = "Contact Form";
  $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
  mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
  echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

I have uploaded these files on my server, you can check it [here](http://qleentreat.me/iDesigner/Basic/index-5.html)

Comment: Can you please let us know which error you are facing?

Comment: I am using this PHP to power my contact form and when I upload it to my server I am not receiving any email instead I receive the message Error! always.

Comment: Can I guess? Are you using apostrophe(`'`) on your inputs?

Comment: Or maybe your `sendmail` not configured?

Comment: How would I configure my send mail?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any error in your code. Probably, your host may have disabled the mail() function

Comment: How would I enable that?